# Adding MIDlet-attributes to JAD file

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, cldc

I am using J2ME Polish to build an application for nokia s40 phones. When i finished packaging the app, i find out that the manifest attributes: "MicroEdition-Configuration" and "MicroEdition-Profile" which is available in the manifest file is not present in the JAD file i.e

```
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

I am using Netbeans to build my project, don't know where the problem will be coming from, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Just open your build-impl.xml in your nbproject folder and in the jad section add this:

```
attribute name="MicroEdition-Configuration" value="CLDC-1.1"/>

attribute name="MicroEdition-Profile" value="MIDP-2.0"/>
```

Of course change them accordingly.